# Why did those plants and flowers start growing super fast?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, justice-league-2017

I saw *Justice League* and there was one part that I was confused by. After the good guys win, we see the family of civilians who've just been saved watching as these magical plants and flowers start blooming supernaturally fast before their eyes. Maybe I missed something, but why are the plants magically speed-growing?

Comment: To set up a sequel..

Answer (score 1):

The energy of the Mother Boxes, originally designed for destruction (more precisely the destruction of what currently existed on the planet in question, replacing it with an ecosystem similar) to Apokalips) instead activated accelerated flora growth, and not necessarily Earth flora either.

It's a fairly common trope - big weapon having an opposite effect when disabled -  but I'd be hard pressed to name it precisely.